# Which OpenID provider to pick?

Tags: openid

With all the big companies providing users with OpenID's and basic usage and many other companies providing various levels of OpenID support who seems to be the leader in full OpenID support? Currently I use VeriSign which has been in "beta" for some time now and while I am happy with them I am sure there are other providers that offer way more control.

What OpenID provider is here to stay, offers control over everything, and is trustworthy to use?

Some links that I have found while looking up providers, delegation and OpenID:

- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/i-just-logged-in-as-you.html
- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/i-just-logged-in-as-you-how-it-happened.html
- http://www.windley.com/archives/2007/02/using_openid_delegation.shtml
- http://openid.net/get-an-openid/

Comment: I recommend on turning this into a community wiki so that multiple OP's can be highlighted and discussed without it turning into a fight for the "best one".

Comment: You actually need to check the box that says "community wiki". Putting "(community wiki)" into the title will not work.

Comment: Which site would this fit in to then, Pro Webmasters? Could this be moved to a better site?

Answer (score 5):

When I started using OpenID, I started to [run my own OpenID server](http://wiki.openid.net/Run-your-own-identity-server). This is so I didn't have to trust any other company/service to do the OpenID authentication for me; I could do it myself. That way, I have full control over everything. That link will direct you to the official OpenID wiki with a list of software that will allow you to host your own OpenID server; from PHP to .NET, it's all there.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using OpenID delegation from your own web site, if you have one, so that your OpenID is a URL *you* control, and so if your OpenID provider becomes less useful/trustworthy you can just switch to a new one. (I do this myself — check out the openid/site in my profile.)

Comment: While I understand the purpose of delegating your OpenID and I am getting this setup you still have to pick a provider at some point.

Comment: Unless of course if you run your own data center ;)